# the horizon of the planck volume?

Tags: event-horizon, space, information

Is there any helpful sense in considering the surface area around the Planck volume as a kind of extremely small horizon, similar to an event horizon or the much larger cosmic horizons in cosmology?

By this I'm not trying to interpret the surface area around the Planck volume as a boundary through which particles and light cannot re-cross after they've crossed towards the interior, but rather as a boundary for anything outside the interior of the surface to receive any information from the inside of the interior of the surface. At this scale, any two points of space would loose any continuous connection with each other. And as marco-observers, we would have no hope of receiving information from volumes at these scales.

This surely reveals my ignorance, but thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the Planck scale we expect quantum effects to be relevant, therefore a putative Planck-sized black hole horizon would fluctuate over the whole horizon itself. In this sense, no portion of space would be really concealed to an external observer.

In these days it's a fairly common belief that geometry and spacetime will be explained as emerging quantities, rather than fundamental, in a complete theory of quantum gravity. Therefore the correct description at those scale will be probably given in terms of relations between quantum fields, for instance entanglement. Notice here that the concept of scale needs the concept of geometry, therefore all these proposal will imply highly non trivial departure from common sense.